# Carregamento de imagem com a implementação Picasso no android

Tags: android, android-studio, imagem, imageview, picasso

Estou usando a implementação Picasso para fazer o carregamento das imagens em minha aplicação. Porém, estou usando o efeito de devaneio da implementação shimmerfacebook para tornar o layout mais agradável para o usuário. Pra quem não conhece, essa implementação é um efeito de brilho que indica que a imagem está sendo carregada. A minha intenção é detectar no picasso quando a imagem foi carrega para que eu possa remover o efeito, já que este só é removido de forma dinâmica.

`Picasso.get().load(https://imagem....).into.(imageView);`

Detectar que a imagem foi carregada.

Answer (score 0):

No ultimo médodo .into() você pode passar um objeto tipo Callback como segundo parâmetro e utilizar o onSuccess() e/ou onError() para saber quando o carregamento do Picasso terminou.

Exemplo do into com callback usando Kotlin:

```
 val requestOptions = Picasso.with(imageView.context).load(imagePath)
 requestOptions.into(this, object :Callback{
        override fun onSuccess() {
            TODO("FAZER ALGO")
        }

        override fun onError() {
            TODO("FAZER ALGO")
        }
    })
```

Javadoc: https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#into-android.widget.ImageView-com.squareup.picasso.Callback-